# Primitive type and Wrapper type for Arrays.asList

Tags: java

I have following simple test case

```
@Test
public void testArraysAsList() {
    Character[] chars1 = new Character[]{'a', 'b'};
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(chars1).size());


    char[] chars2 = new char[]{'a', 'b'};
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(chars2).size());

}
```

The result is:
2
1

I don't understand `Arrays.asList(chars2)`, why `Arrays.asList(char[])` makes a one size list,with the element being char[].

Comment: Because generics only work with reference types.

Comment: This would make a good example of java pitfalls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Andy explains, generics only work with reference types. That means that `List<char>` is not allowed (so `Arrays.asList` cannot return `List<char>`). Instead `Arrays.asList` interprets its input as a single object and returns a list with that single element.

```
    Character[] chars1 = new Character[]{'a', 'b'};
    List<Character> list1 = Arrays.asList(chars1);

    char[] chars2 = new char[]{'a', 'b'};
    List<char[]> list2 = Arrays.asList(chars2);
```

Compare `Arrays.asList(chars2)` with this `String` example (where the input is also is a single element):

```
    String test = "test";
    List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(test);
```

Returns a list with size()==1

Comment: Got it..doesn't understand it from the Generic perspective,

Answer (score 4):

Collections can contain only objects not primitive types.

> java.util.Arrays.asList(T... a) here T can be an object not primitive.

And in the case of **Arrays.asList(char[])**, it will be considering **char[]** as an object (T). so you will see unexpected characters on printing below:

> System.out.println(Arrays.asList(chars2));

Output :

> [[C@15db9742]

And the size will be one always for primitive types arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It is so because List accepts only Objects not primitives. So when you pass an array of Objects it takes those Objects and creates a list of it. But when you pass an Array of primitives, it takes the Array itself (which is an Object) and creates the List. 
In the first case there were 2 objects so the length of list was 2. Whereas in the second case there is only one object (i.e. the array itself) so the length will be 1 now.

Following code will make it clear

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.testArraysAsList();
    }
    public void testArraysAsList() {
        Character[] chars1 = new Character[]{'a', 'b'};
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(chars1).size());


        char[] chars2 = new char[]{'a', 'b'};
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(chars2).size());

        Integer[] int1 = new Integer[]{1, 2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(int1));

        int[][] int2 = new int[][]{{1,2},{1,2} };
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(int2));


    }
}
```

Now look at the output obtained by running the above code on my machine.

```
2
1
[1, 2]
[[I@1540e19d, [I@677327b6]
```

Since the `int2` array is two dimensional array, it has 2 arrays in it. So it has 2 objects in it. So the length is 2 in this case. You can see it in the output, the `[[I@1540e19d` and  `[I@677327b6]` are the 2 array objects this time.

Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Because chars2 is an object, but 'a' and 'b' are chars, and char is a primitive type, not an object type. So chars2 is used as the first (and only) element in the resulting list.